# IntelliJ/AS - How to switch Logcat filters with only one click?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, filter, android-studio, logcat

My IntelliJ IDEA logcat window looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, to switch between filters I need to first click on the dropdown menu and then select the filter I want. However, I have seen a screenshot online that looks like this:

[image]

That is exactly what I want because it seems you can switch between filters with only one click (like Eclipse). How can I make my filters to be on the left like the second picture so I can switch between filters with only one click?

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I have found that you can get the Eclipse style logcat window in Android Studio is by opening the Android Device Monitor.

`Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor`

The bottom half of the window should have the logcat window.

[image: Android Device Monitor]